# JSON_value to find pair of nested json

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a JSON as below, which is stored in a varchar column in SQL Server.

```
@jsonbody = '{"info":"new","details":{"address":[{"town":"saltlake"},{"town":"twncity"}]}}'
```

I want to get the value of each key from the JSON. I'm able to get the value by using `JSON_VALUE()` and got the first one.

```
select JSON_VALUE(@jsonbody,'$.info') -- new
```

How to get value of "details" as below:

```
'{"address":[{"town":"saltlake"},{"town":"twncity"}]}'
```

Comment: With `JSON_QUERY()` : `SELECT JSON_VALUE (d.JsonData, '$.info') AS info, JSON_QUERY(d.JsonData, '$.details') AS address FROM #Data d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON_VALUE` used to extract a scalar value from a JSON string.

To extract an object or an array you need to use [`JSON_QUERY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) :

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(@jsonbody,'$.details');
```

Comment: Thank you @selvazi for the quick response